# Search with partial name in Windows 10 start menu

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, cortana

Is it possible to search in Windows 10 from start menu with part of an application name?

**Example**

I have `qBittorrent` app. If I start searching with `torrent` I see no results.

[image]

In contrast, if I search for `word` I get `Microsoft Office Word` because it's searching word-wise.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It may be you haven't indexed the *Start Menu* in Windows *Search*. On my PC, Window 10 v. 1803 (10.0.17134.112), searching on the (quite) incomplete `nybu` returned the application *AnyBurn*, as expected.

[image: Searching in Windows 10]

To include the *Start Menu* in the index,

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type `index`.
- Select *Indexing Options*
- If *Start Menu* is not being indexed, click Modify* to add it.

[image: Adding Start Menu to Search]

Comment: Since it can find the application, how come it needs indexing? Although, rebuilt index and startmenu indexed.

Comment: MS is glad to add *its own* products to Search index... you have to add others.

Comment: I can see the result I want. I cannot search it partially

Comment: I have Start Menu in the index and I still cannot search apps by partial names.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. My start menu is indexed and it doesn't return partial hits. Also, what kind of start menu is that? It doesn't look like a W10 start menu.

Comment: This is a known bug that isn't fixed until Windows 11. There is no earlier version of Windows that provides for a reliable fix (*no*, none of `dism`, `sfc`, nor rebuilding the search index will help). You must reinstall Windows from scratch in the earlier versions.