# Is "Start Menu" "Partial Search" disabled by default in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, start-menu, windows-search

I can't make "partial searches" in windows 10 Start Menu.
Is anyone having the same problem?
In "indexing options" the "Start Menu" is in "Included Location" and has nothing "Excluded" (although the "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu" is selected none of parent folders show the standard "part selected" icon. WTF M$??? Also there was a strange URL that aparenttly pointed nowhere)
"Windows Search Settings"->"Excluded Folders" contains a "C:\ProgramData" entry.
I didn't touch these settings so, besides the obvious "which one has precedence?"...

Are these the default settings??

PS:
This seams to be an old problem:
[Search with partial name in Windows 10 start menu - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1335736/search-with-partial-name-in-windows-10-start-menu)
[[HELP] Partial search not working : Windows10](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/6e727c/help_partial_search_not_working/)

Well...aparently there's some complicated hacky solution:
[Windows Search down for many — here's the fix | Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-search-down-many-showing-blank-box-instead-search-results)

I'll try removing "C:\ProgramData" entry (although I should be necessary has just really want to search a deep nested folder) and then the hacky one and post the results

Comment: Has it should removing "C:\ProgramData" entry did nothing

Comment: also found this:  
[Cortana doesn't find partial words. Search for "Stopwatch" - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cortana-doesnt-find-partial-words-search-for/a8d8d650-e5ab-4a0a-836c-f0f2760cd402)

Comment: Is this Windows pushing users to use a "way to invasive" mechanism to do a simple task?

Comment: Try updating Windows and then Rebuild your Index.  The links you posted are old and problems have been fixed.

Comment: Isn't this procedure just as invasive?  
[Windows Search down for many — here's the fix | Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-search-down-many-showing-blank-box-instead-search-results)  
Would I be agreeing with to let them monitor me?

Comment: Thanks @John
Gee!! you got the "John" nick! Founding member? :-)

Comment: That fix was repaired by Microsoft within hours of it appearing

Comment: Is asking about ethical aspects of software companies behavior ("regarding specific technical issues") of topic here?
It shouldn't....it's definetly on" users" interest

Comment: By the way...this they solve this just this year?  
[Rebuild Search Index in Windows 10 | Tutorials](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/58569-rebuild-search-index-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: You have always been able to fix and rebuild the index.  If there are errors that have affected you, Microsoft has been addressing them on an ongoing basis

Comment: @John Rebuilt the index, restarted....nothing!! typing "vpn" doesn't find the protonvpt.lnk existing in the start menu folder

Comment: Starting from the middle of the word has always been difficult. *ord found word but other starts did not work.

Comment: Partial search is a standart in every database for many decades now. I'm starting to feel manipulated a bit here! Not by you, by microsoft. And the most annoyingly, not in a subtle way!

Comment: By the way, if you have more than 3000 points in reputation...could you create the tag "ethics"?

Comment: And apparently they're spying by default:  
[How to Disable Bing in the Windows 10 Start Menu](https://www.howtogeek.com/224159/how-to-disable-bing-in-the-windows-10-start-menu/)